# TableViewController selective cells gets deselected on table reload

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an issue where some cells are deselected when i try to reload the rows/table with refresh controller and scroll the tableview immediately. i checked it with the deselection in diSelectrow and in didDeselectRow.In both methods the debug counter isn't encountered.
i have the following code in cellforRow

```
if (isEditClicked == true || [indexarray containsObject:indexPath]) {
    [cardinboxCardCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault];
}
```

following in didselectrow

```
if (!self.tableView.isEditing) {
    Card *card;
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    card = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushToMyCardDetails" sender:card];
}else {
    selectedDeleteCardCount += 1;
    if (deleBtn) {
        [deleBtn setEnabled:true];
    }
    [indexarray addObject:indexPath];
    NSString* cardsCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%d)",selectedDeleteCardCount];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitle:cardsCount];
}
```

following in didDeselctrow

```
if (self.tableView.isEditing) {
    selectedDeleteCardCount -= 1;
    NSString* cardsCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Inbox"];
    [indexarray removeObject:indexPath];
    if (selectedDeleteCardCount != 0){
        cardsCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%d)",selectedDeleteCardCount];
        if (deleBtn) {[deleBtn setEnabled:true];}
    }else {
        if (deleBtn) {[deleBtn setEnabled:false];}
    }
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitle:cardsCount];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have doubt over indexpath object, might be this object has changed.. so thats why this condition is failing

```
if (isEditClicked == true || [indexarray containsObject:indexPath]) {
```

My advice to you is **check with section and row index** not for object itself like this

```
//find indexPath (row and section) in indexarray using for loop to retrive whether 
//is this cell is selected or not

     bool isCellSelected = [self currentIndexPathSelected:indexPath];
    if (isEditClicked == true || isCellSelected) {
    }
```

Comment: Hi, i have checked and got the logs of index paths of selected rows, even when i have three index in array, sometime none are selected and sometimes all are selected and sometimes only partially two rows are selected and one row isn't selcted.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to maintain States for all cell. You can use Bool isSelected. Whenever you select any cell mark it true at index of state. same as deselect mark it false. :-)

Comment: am already maintaining the selected cell indexes in indexarray.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try and maintain the selected state in the UI. Store it independently so it can be restored when you reload the tableview.

I would in general advise against storing the selected indexes or indexPaths as the relationship between these and your model can change if items are inserted/deleted/reordered. (may not apply in your case though, but still better to avoid this potential issue)

Instead store the selected model objects, then you will always know exactly what is selected and nothing can mess with this. Just make the mutable array 'selected' and add remove them as needed.

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is where you add/remove the model object from the selected array.
`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is where you set the cell selected state dependant on the selected array.

Answer (score -1):

IN order to achieve what you are looking for, your set up should look something like this:

[image]

Now focus on this part:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = object[@"text"];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:object[@"image"]];
    if (_selectedIndexPaths[[self getKey:indexPath]] != nil) cell.selected = [_selectedIndexPaths[indexPath] boolValue];
    return cell;
}

- (NSString *) getKey : (NSIndexPath *) path {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld-%ld", (long)path.section, (long)path.row];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [_selectedIndexPaths setValue:@(TRUE) forKey:[self getKey:indexPath]];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelected:true];

    //[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

As you can see we set a value in `_selectedIndexPaths` while cell get selected, and when in cell is constructed that check allow us to keep selection alive. You can use same pattern with checkMark accessory as well.